# numpy - return index If value inside one of 3d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, collect

How to do this in Numpy : Thank you!

**Input :**

```
A = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3]) 

B = np.array([[3, 2, 0], [0, 2, 1], [2, 3, 1], [3, 0, 1]])
```

---

**Output :**

```
result = [[0, 1, 3], [1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 3]]
```

---

in Python :

```
A = np.array([0 ,1 ,2 ,3]) 
B = np.array([[3 ,2 ,0], [0 ,2 ,1], [2 ,3 ,1], [3 ,0 ,1]]) 
result = []
for x ,  valA in enumerate (A) :
    inArray = []
    for y , valB in enumerate (B) : 
        if valA in valB:
            inArray.append (y)
    result.append (inArray)
print result

# result = [[0, 1, 3], [1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's a NumPy vectorized approach using [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
R,C = np.where((A[:,None,None] == B).any(-1))
out = np.split(C,np.flatnonzero(R[1:]>R[:-1])+1)
```

**Approach #2**

Assuming `A` and `B` to hold positive numbers, we can consider those to represent indices on a `2D` grid, such that `B` could be considered to hold the column indices on per row basis. Once that `2D` grid corresponding to `B` is in place, we just need to consider only the columns that are intersected by `A`. Finally, we get the indices of `True` values in a such a `2D` grid to give us `R` and `C` values. This should be much more memory-efficient.

Thus, the alternative approach would look something like this -

```
ncols = B.max()+1
nrows = B.shape[0]
mask = np.zeros((nrows,ncols),dtype=bool)
mask[np.arange(nrows)[:,None],B] = 1
mask[:,~np.in1d(np.arange(mask.shape[1]),A)] = 0
R,C = np.where(mask.T)
out = np.split(C,np.flatnonzero(R[1:]>R[:-1])+1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [43]: A
Out[43]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])

In [44]: B
Out[44]: 
array([[3, 2, 0],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [2, 3, 1],
       [3, 0, 1]])

In [45]: out
Out[45]: [array([0, 1, 3]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 2, 3])]
```

**Runtime test**

Scaling up the dataset sizes by `100x`, here's a quick runtime test result -

```
In [85]: def index_1din2d(A,B):
    ...:     R,C = np.where((A[:,None,None] == B).any(-1))
    ...:     out = np.split(C,np.flatnonzero(R[1:]>R[:-1])+1)
    ...:     return out
    ...: 
    ...: def index_1din2d_initbased(A,B):
    ...:     ncols = B.max()+1
    ...:     nrows = B.shape[0]
    ...:     mask = np.zeros((nrows,ncols),dtype=bool)
    ...:     mask[np.arange(nrows)[:,None],B] = 1
    ...:     mask[:,~np.in1d(np.arange(mask.shape[1]),A)] = 0
    ...:     R,C = np.where(mask.T)
    ...:     out = np.split(C,np.flatnonzero(R[1:]>R[:-1])+1)
    ...:     return out
    ...: 

In [86]: A = np.unique(np.random.randint(0,10000,(400)))
    ...: B = np.random.randint(0,10000,(400,300))
    ...: 

In [87]: %timeit [np.where((B == x).sum(axis = 1))[0] for x in A]
1 loop, best of 3: 161 ms per loop # @Psidom's soln

In [88]: %timeit index_1din2d(A,B)
10 loops, best of 3: 91.5 ms per loop

In [89]: %timeit index_1din2d_initbased(A,B)
10 loops, best of 3: 33.4 ms per loop
```

**Further performance-boost!**

Well, alternatively we can create the `2D` grid in the second approach in a transposed way. The idea is to avoid the transpose in `R,C = np.where(mask.T)`, which seemed like the bottleneck. So, a modified version of the second approach and the associated runtimes would look something like this -

```
In [135]: def index_1din2d_initbased_v2(A,B):
     ...:     nrows = B.max()+1
     ...:     ncols = B.shape[0]
     ...:     mask = np.zeros((nrows,ncols),dtype=bool)
     ...:     mask[B,np.arange(ncols)[:,None]] = 1
     ...:     mask[~np.in1d(np.arange(mask.shape[0]),A)] = 0
     ...:     R,C = np.where(mask)
     ...:     out = np.split(C,np.flatnonzero(R[1:]>R[:-1])+1)
     ...:     return out
     ...: 

In [136]: A = np.unique(np.random.randint(0,10000,(400)))
     ...: B = np.random.randint(0,10000,(400,300))
     ...: 

In [137]: %timeit index_1din2d_initbased(A,B)
10 loops, best of 3: 57.5 ms per loop

In [138]: %timeit index_1din2d_initbased_v2(A,B)
10 loops, best of 3: 25.9 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with a combination of `numpy` and `list-comprehension`:

```
import numpy as np
[np.where((B == x).sum(axis = 1))[0] for x in A]
# [array([0, 1, 3]), array([1, 2, 3]), array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 2, 3])]
```